# Easiest way to keep only last column after splitting text to columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm using pandas and I have a dataframe where one column looks like

1. abc/def/ghi/jkl
2. mno/pqr/stu/vwx/yz
3. 123/23/24/24/24/53/523/23/111

What I'm trying to do is split the text to columns (delimiter of /) and keep only the last column so that the data looks like:

1. jkl
2. yz
3. 111

Is there any relatively simple way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why second is `mno` ? it is not `yz` ?

Comment: Because I'm a spoon :D fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing for select last value of lists:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

If no missing values and performance is important use list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [x.split('/')[-1] for x in df['col']]
```

---

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.split('/').str[-1]
print (df)
                             col  new
0                abc/def/ghi/jkl  jkl
1             mno/pqr/stu/vwx/yz   yz
2  123/23/24/24/24/53/523/23/111  111
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, is it possible to apply this to all columns at the same time? (100+ in my case)

Comment: @Jordan - all columns in DataFrame are strings with `/` and need split them? Or need specify columns some way, by positions or by names?

Comment: yes exactly, all columns are strings with / and needed to be split (and keep last value as before), thanks again for the help, I'm new to python as you can see :)

Comment: @Jordan - Use `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/').str[-1])`

Comment: Got the following error
('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', u'occurred at index contributor')

Comment: @Jordan - it means there are some non string columns, use `df = df.select_dtypes(object).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/').str[-1])`

Comment: @Jordan - Ok, so what about `df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('/').str[-1])` ?

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks again you are a hero haha